# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView(Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-recyclerview

I want use android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in my android project in eclipse

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ir.sheikhoo.sis.EditeActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but it throws an error

```
09-23 11:33:37.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.sheikhoo.sis/ir.sheikhoo.sis.EditeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

full error log

```
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333): Process: ir.sheikhoo.sis, PID: 28333
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.sheikhoo.sis/ir.sheikhoo.sis.EditeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:331)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2018)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at ir.sheikhoo.sis.EditeActivity.onCreate(EditeActivity.java:13)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    ... 11 more
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.sheikhoo.sis-22.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ir.sheikhoo.sis-22, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:566)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703)
09-23 11:55:53.288: E/AndroidRuntime(28333):    ... 21 more
```

I use `android.support-23.2.1` and target sdk `android:targetSdkVersion="23"`

[image]

it's my sdk

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete error log - or is that all? The error usually points to some exception in the Activity- in this case `EditeActivity`.

Comment: My recommendation is to use Android Studio with gradle. It is way easier to use libs like recyclerview and you will have more fun while developing ;-)

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i add complete error log

Comment: Your jar is in a directory called `libs` and you have added dependencies for only `lib`, I think. Please check the dependencies.

Comment: add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" into Relativelayout.

Comment: @IshitaSinha no it's libs

Comment: @AsifPatel no it's not work

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your **cardview** jar file, it does not match version with other libraries.

1st, you mast need to use **cardview** or other libraries version less than **compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion**. In this case you use version **cardview-v7-21.0.0.jar** so your **compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion** must be 21.0.0 or upper.

2nd, I think you need to switch Android Studio it's made easy to manage libraries.

Comment: i change all libs to android.support-23.2.1 and use api 23 for target... i change my post