# How should I set up RecyclerView version to match my project?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

It's been a while I'm trying to run/code a RecyclerView example, with no success though. I guess it has something to do with the RecyclerView version used in dependencies and the Android versions my project is using.
Currently, I'm trying to run this example [here](http://technxt.net/android-cardview-with-recyclerview-in-android-cardview-android/).

It doesn't mention what are the compileSdkVersion,  minSdkVersion and so on. 
Anyway, here's my **gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deluxe.example"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Also in this example, the Adapter imports **android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView, for which I get an error: Cannot resolve symbol v7**. So, Android suggested importing  **androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView**;

Issue: my project doesn't load the RecyclerView in the MainActivity - it throws an exception: 
*Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView*
for which although there're similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477860/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656003/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-recyclervieweclipse) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709571/didnt-find-class-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview/29709712), I couldn't solve my issue.

I'm new to Android Studio, so can anyone suggest what should I change in order to run this Recycler/CardView example? I've tried several examples already, but wasn't able to run any of them - recent and older ones. 
I'm trying to run using Android Nougat(7.0) and upper, but it's not mandatory. And **my Android Studio version is 3.5.1**

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using Androidx (good), then you need to import the corresponding artifacts:

`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta04'` (or whatever latest version exists)

And then in all the places where you reference RecyclerView, (hint: use Android studio "find" and search for the term `recyclerview` to find and evaluate all references and places where it's mentioned), and ensure you are referencing the new artifacts, e.g.:

`import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` in code and

`<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView ...` in XML.

While you are at it, remove

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

And if you can, replace:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

with:

```
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10"
```

And use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
```

in your XMLs.

Comment: Thanks, I changed accordingly, and I was able to see the layout at least. Couldn;t run the app though.. I got different errors which I believe are related to another issue.